# Merge multiple sites into one

Tags: php, android, python, android-webview

I am creating an android app that will display a webview of recent news and upcoming events. The webview html page I would like to be dynamic content that is populated from different sites that the city has. For example, police, parks and rec and news the mayor releases.

I am not worried about formatting or styling I just want to know if it is possible to pull in specific content (classes/IDs) and merge them into 1 website. If possible I would like to leverage PHP but can use python if it will accomplish the task. The only language that I can not use is javascript, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is very possible. I've done it many times. What you'll need to do is something called screen scraping. I commonly use regular expressions for screen scraping, as the target site's content format usually doesn't change.

Here's a good in-depth tutorial on it: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library--net-11856

Comment: Perfect!! That is exactly what I have been looking for, never could figure out what it was called. Thanks